# MongoDB schema design: reference by ID vs. reference by name?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

With this simple example
(use short ObjectId to make it read easier)

Tag documents:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('0001'),
    name: 'JavaScript',
    // other data
},
{
    _id: ObjectId('0002'),
    name: 'MongoDB',
    // other data
},
...
```

Assume that we need a individual `tag` collection, e.g. we need to store some information on each tag.

If reference by ID:

```
// a book document
{
    _id: ObjectId('9876'),
    title: 'MEAN Web Development',
    tags: [ObjectId('0001'), ObjectId('0002'), ...]
}
```

If reference by name:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('9876'),
    title: 'MEAN Web Development',
    tags: ['JavaScript', 'MongoDB', ...]
}
```

It's known that "reference by ID" is feasible.

I'm thinking if use "reference by name", a query for book's info only need to find within the `book` collection, we could know the tags' name without a join (`$lookup`) operation, which should be faster.

If the app performs a tag checking before book creating and modifying, this should also be feasible, and faster.

I'm still not very sure:

1. Is there any hider on "reference by name" ?
2. Will "reference by name" slower on "finding all books with a given tag" ? Maybe `ObjectId` is somehow special ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it depends on what your use case is for tags. As you say, it will be more expensive to do a `$lookup` to retrieve tag names if you reference by id. On the other hand, if you expect that tag names may change frequently, all documents in the book collection containing that tag will need to be updated every change.

The ObjectID is simply a 12 byte value, which is autogenerated by a driver if no `_id` is present in inserted documents. See the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) for more info. The only "special behavior" would be the fact that `_id` [has an index by default](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/). An index will speedup lookups in general, but indexes can be created on any field, not just `_id`.

In fact, the `_id` does not need to be an ObjectID. It is perfectly legal to have documents with integer `_id` values for instance:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Javascript'
},
{
    _id: 2,
    name: 'MongoDB'
},
```